# Functional equation of the complete $L$-function of the twisted $L$-function of a cuspidal modular form

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, dirichlet-series, l-functions

Let $f(z)=\sum a(n)n^{(k-1)/2}q^n\in S_k(\Gamma_0(N),\chi)$ a cuspidal modular form of integral weight with nebentypus $\chi.$ I am looking for the expression of $\Lambda(\psi\otimes f,s)$ the complete $L$-function (In the sense of Iwaniec's book Analytic number theory page 94) of the twisted $L$-function of  $f$ by a caracter $\psi\; :$
$$L(\psi\otimes f,s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{a(n)}{n^s}\psi(n)$$
and his functional equation. Can someone give me a reference in which i can find it ?

Thanks!

Comment: @user1952009, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You know [this method](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,1308891,1344176#msg-1344176) for defining $L(f \times g,s)$ when $f,g \in M_k(\Gamma_0(N)),S_m(\Gamma_0(M))$ ? In the case you wrote ($k$ half-integral weight and $\chi$ non-trivial) the Poisson summation formula and the real Eisenstein series become messy, and the [adelic formulation](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/) becomes a good idea.

Comment: The answer is reasonably straightforward (and the proof follows by classical means) when the conductors of $f$ and $\psi$ are coprime. See Proposition 14.20 of Iwaniec and Kowalski. When the conductors of $f$ and $\psi$ are not coprime, however, then you really have no recourse but to work adelically.

Comment: ...well, that's not quite true, because in some cases (e.g. when the conductor of $f$ is squarefree) you can still do it classically. But it becomes quite complicated.